# Border extending past text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The content and links are generated by WordPress in which the output is

```css
#s-text p {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.9);
}
#s-text a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="s-text">
  <p>...content ...
    <a href "">link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

This way works with the link appearing below the text except the border around the link goes to both edges (not just around the link) when I change to inline-block, the border issue gets fixed but the link lines in with the text.

I want the border to just surround the text, and the link to be centered underneath the content. Although I can't remove it from outside the `<p>` tags

Comment: Your snippet doesn't help much, since you can't see anything.  Mind making it work so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you expect? Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Used `display: table` and `margin: 20px auto` for the `a` tag.

```css
#s-text {
  background: #ddd;
}

#s-text p {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.9);
}
#s-text a {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="s-text">
  <p>...content ...
    <a href="">link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: that does what I want, I've just always been told to avoid using table

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your link inside span tag and then style your span with Jquery to center it by giving position and left attribute values accordingly.

```
.link {
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
}
```

this will center your link at position fixed from left no matter how long the link is.
So you need to compute this left value according to width of your link.

[this fiddle might help for the situation stated above(same size linktext)](https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/uxeLuw53/1/)